# QUIC support for Kubernetes Ingress Controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, quic, http3

Has anyone deployed QUIC with a supported/official Kubernetes Ingress Controller? I have been using the NGINX ingress so far and support for QUIC seems to be NOT there at present.

Comment: Maybe you could try exposing it with [Nginx UDP service exposal](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/)

Comment: You could build nginx with quic module, refer to [Binary Packages Now Available for the Preview NGINX QUIC+HTTP/3 Implementation](https://www.nginx.com/blog/binary-packages-for-preview-nginx-quic-http3-implementation/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=nginxdb&utm_campaign=ww-nx_ssap_g&utm_content=bg&mkt_tok=NjUzLVNNQy03ODMAAAGLXzLAvUPVuXhrwz156RWFYOQQeuMJQ6hDd-hVFpKvfou1SwmuisSw6seJR5P_QgjR3NMxLX61oQbCbrQV1w8sq0MHDwNvwITYs1WHrJHiUG9e7fumC80)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QUIC/HTTP3](https://bunny.net/academy/cdn/what-is-http-3-quic-protocol/)  is not yet available in the `Stable Nginx` and to be available in the Nginx ingress controller will defiantly take time.

> Product Management tells me that we hope to fully support QUIC and HTTP/3 by the end of 2022. Note that this is not a promise :-)

[our-roadmap-quic-http-3-support-nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/our-roadmap-quic-http-3-support-nginx/)

QUIC/HTTP3 will be targeted in the Nginx ingress controller once nginx release becomes stable.

> we have just upgraded to nginx 1.20.1 and from here https://quic.nginx.org/README it looks that **HTTP/3 is still experimental so not until there is a stable release will we be implementing HTTP/3.**

Here is the feature request [[FEATURE REQUEST] HTTP/3 support](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/4760)

You can try the [nginx docker image that show how to build with quick support](https://www.nginx.com/blog/our-roadmap-quic-http-3-support-nginx/#How-You-Can-Help) and try to use Network Load Balancer hope that will work.